# Expected value of nonnegative variable inequality with infinite series

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that when $X$ is nonnegative random variable then 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \geq n) \leq \mathbb{E}X \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \geq n)
$$

I know that 
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n)
$$

I thought about tweaking left side this way:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \geq n) \leq \mathbb{E}X \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \geq n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 - \mathbb{P}(X < n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 - \left(\mathbb{P}(X \leq n) - \mathbb{P}(X = n) \right) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq n) + \mathbb{P}(X = n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) + \mathbb{P}(X = n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1 - F_X(n) \\
$$
but it did not lead me anywhere. How can we prove both left and right hand sides?

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3401779/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximate $X$ by step functions:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cdot\mathbb1_{\{X \in [n, n+1)\}}\ \ \leq X \leq 1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cdot\mathbb1_{\{X \in [n, n+1)\}}. $$

Now take expectations:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\mathbb{P}(X \in [n, n+1)) \leq \mathbb{E}(X) \leq 1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \mathbb{P}(X \in [n, n+1)). $$

These are just an equivalent form of the given inequalities.

Comment: Could you explain why $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb1_{X\in[n,n+1)}) = \mathbb{P}(X \in [n,n+1))$?

Comment: One could say: it’s the definition. ;-) Remember that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is the integral of $X$ with respect to the measure $\mathbb{P}$. Or, the indicator function only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ so its expectation is $0\ \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{value}=0) + 1 \ \mathbb{P}( \mathrm{value} = 1)$.