# Prove for non-negative RV , $\mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol{X}\}$ is finite iff $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)$ converges for all $\epsilon>0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

I want to know how to prove that for a **non-negative** random variable **X**,  its first moment is finite ($\mathbb{E}\left\{X\right\}<\infty$ ) if and only if
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon) \text { converges for all } \epsilon>0
$$
I tried to upperbound and lowerbound the expectation with quantities related to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n \epsilon)$ but with no result.

Any ideas??

Comment: An alternative to the answer provided below: For any $X\geq 0$ we have the identity $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>t) \, \text dt$. I haven't worked out the details, but you should be able to use this in combination with the integral test for convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n\epsilon) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(\frac{X}{\epsilon} \geq n) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\Bbb{E}[X]<+\infty$

Comment: isn't the Expectation formula with the sum valid only for discrete random variables?? In the case of continuous, how to go from the convergence of the sum to the moment being finite??

Comment: @The_NooB it is true for every random variable with finite expectaion..See Kai Lang Chungs book ''A probability Course''

Comment: What if $Y=1/2$? $\mathsf{E}Y=1/2$; however, $\mathsf{P}(Y\ge n)=0$ for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. i edited.

Comment: I think that there must be an inequality $\le$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399424/compare-expectation-of-probability-to-the-infinite-sum-of-probability/3401830).

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes you are right! thank you