# For any random variable $X$, I need to show that $E(|X|) < ∞$ if and only if $\sum_{n \geq1}P(|X| > nε) < ∞$ for every $ε$ > 0

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For any random variable $X$, I need to show that $E(|X|) < ∞$ if and only if $\sum_{n \geq1}P(|X| > nε) < ∞$ for every $ε$ > 0.

My approach was using the Markov inequality with $P(|X|^2 > (nε)^2) \leq \frac {E(|X|^2)}{(n\epsilon)^2}$ and then trying to use the Chebyshev inequality for some bounds on the $X^2$ term but I did not reach anywhere.

I am now guessing that my approcah was way off and this requires either analysis or some algebraic jugglery. Really stuck on this for a while. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: I believe it was answered here few times already, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032409/prove-for-non-negative-rv-mathbbe-boldsymbolx-is-finite-iff-sum)

Comment: If $Y \geq 0$, then by Tonelli's theorem, $$E(Y) = E(\int_{0}^{\infty}I(y \leq Y)\,dy) = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(y \leq Y)\,dy.$$ You can compare this integral to summations to deduce your result.